# XSS mitigation with url encoded input

Tags: javascript, java, xss, owasp, html-encode

In one of my application to mitigate XSS attack I am using Encoder for html from OWASP but unfortunately it is not sufficient.

The pentesters have found a reflected cross site scripting threat where the input field content or the payload is URL encoded, the XSS encode/filter does not encode the data and allow the input to pass to the Javascript function.

The input is: %3Cscript%3Ealert%285%29%3C%2Fscript%3E or 39848%3balert(1)%2f%2f920

I have also tried Jsoup en html sanitize. They all are filtering the output/input only for html but this is already in a encoded form.

```
    function set() {
var span = window.parent.document.all.<%=Encode.forHtml(request.getParameter("address"))%>;
var action = '<%=Encode.forHtml(request.getParameter("action"))%>';

<logic:present name="postcodeForm" property="result">
<bean:size id="resultSize" name="postcodeForm" property="result"/>
<logic:notMatch name="resultSize" value="1">
span.innerHTML = "<bean:message key='error.result'/>";
span.className = "errSpec";

</logic:notMatch>
<logic:match name="resultSize" value="1">
<logic:iterate id="adres" name="postcodeForm" property="result">
span.innerHTML = "<bean:write name='address' property='Street'/>&nbsp;"
+ <%=Integer.parseInt(Encode.forHtml(searchString.substring(searchString.indexOf(',') + 1)))%>
<logic:present parameter="houseNumber">
<%=Encode.forHtml(request.getParameter("houseNumber"))%>
</logic:present>
+ "<br/>" + "<bean:write name='address' property='postcode'/>&nbsp;<bean:write name='address' property='houseNr'/>";
span.className = "";

if (action == 'postcode') {
var streetname= "<bean:write name='address' property='streetName' filter="false"/>";
```

Any idea or help is highly appreciated.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: What is your app supposed to do with _legitimate_ input? Interpret it as HTML code? Or just as text? Or...?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Thanks for replying!
So in the application the value of the parameter gets picked up and then being used in javascript function. It is mainly simple string/text value.            See the code below:                                                                                                    
 `function set() {
var span = window.parent.document.all.<%=Encode.forHtml(request.getParameter("address"))%>;
var action = '<%=Encode.forHtml(request.getParameter("action"))%>';`

Comment: Can you give an example of what this Javascript code shall do for _legitimate_ input? It currently seems that attackers can produce arbitrary Javascript by supplying suitable input.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen It varies. I pasted the code snippet for this particular jsp:

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Thanks for your support. I have like more that 100 JSPs en definitely more than that javascript functions. Is there no generic way to do it may be? If I make a filter and intercept all the request and filter out because otherwise i have to like change every var or field in a jsp/javascript..

Comment: Since your parameters differ in their meaning (`action` is a string but `address` is not), I doubt there is a simple generic solution. Unless you are very restrictive and disallow all special characters (allowing only letters and digits, say).

Answer (score 0):

Complexity is greatly decreased if all your request parameters are string values that occur in Javascript code. You need then only make sure that

- any string delimiters that occur in a request parameter are properly escaped (`"` becomes `\"`) and
- the backslash is escaped (`\` becomes `\\`) so that parameters cannot themselves contain escape sequences.

No HTML encoding is necessary for that.

You current code does not treat `address` as a string value, you should write `window.parent.document.all["XXX"]` instead of `window.parent.document.all.XXX`. This is produced with the following server-side code:

```
var span = window.parent.document.all["<%=
  request.getParameter("address")
   .replaceAll('"', '\\"')
   .replaceAll('\\', '\\\\')
%>"];
var action = "<%=
  request.getParameter("action")
   .replaceAll('"', '\\"')
   .replaceAll('\\', '\\\\')
%>";
```

Even if an attacker set `address` to the value `"];alert(1)`, this would still be treated as a string:

```
var span = window.parent.document.all["\"];alert(1)"];
```

(I do not understand your current treatment of `houseNumber`, but this must also be handled as a string.)